# Changing value of a combo box Ext.form.ComboBox Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having a little trouble setting the value of a combo box within the code.

I have the following select box

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
             id: 'address_type',
             name: 'address_type',
             editable: false,
             disableKeyFilter: true,
             forceSelection: true,
             fieldLabel: 'Type',
             emptyText: 'Please Select',
             triggerAction: 'all',
             mode: 'local',
             store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
              id: 0,
              fields: ['value', 'text'],
              data : [['Home', 'Home Address'], ['Work', 'Work Address']]
             }),
             valueField: 'value',
             displayField: 'text',
             hiddenName: 'address_type'
            })
```

So surely if I executed:

```
Ext.getCmp('address_type').setValue('Work')
```

Would set the value of the select box to 'Work Address'? However it doesn't appear to work.

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that `Ext.getCmp` call is failing because you have defined identical `id` and `hiddenName` for the `ComboBox`.

[ExtJS (now Sencha) API documentation](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/) states the following:

> **hiddenName : String**
>
> If specified, a hidden form field with
>   this name is dynamically generated to
>   store the field's data value. ...
>
> Note: the hidden field's id will also
>   default to this name if hiddenId is
>   not specified. The ComboBox id and the
>   hiddenId should be different, since no
>   two DOM nodes should share the same
>   id. So, if the ComboBox name and
>   hiddenName are the same, you should
>   specify a unique hiddenId.

So, you should try to give your `Combobox` a unique `hiddenId` and see if it works then.

Comment: Ahhhh! I should have looked a little closer at the docs! Thank you very much.